# How do I web-scrape the table that just reflects Texas Rangers season from the following link? I am using BeautifulSoup4 and html.parser

Tags: python, web-scraping

Here's what I tried:

```
import requests
website_url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Texas_Rangers_seasons"
url = requests.get(website_url).text
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(website_url,'html.parser')

# Selecting the table
table_classes = {"class":"wikitable plainrowheaders"}
rel_table = soup.find_all('table',table_classes)
```

I am not sure how to proceed further. I did inspect the elements and it appears that the title and href are both dynamic with year field in it. As well, it also contains table for Washington Senators. I would appreciate any help on this! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Texas_Rangers_seasons'
r = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,'lxml')

#method 1
for row in soup.select('table.plainrowheaders tr')[14:]:
    for cell in row.select('td'):
        print(cell.text.strip(), end=' ')
    print()

#method 2
for row in soup.select('table.plainrowheaders tr')[14:]:
    print(row.get_text(strip=True, separator=' '))
```

Comment: If you could also help me with another simple thing, can a string be split by two or more conditions using str.split? Not really looking for using regular expression re package. Thanks!

Comment: I don't have an answer to that one. I'm sorry